# limsup of a sequence vs limsup of a subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X$ be a set and let $(E_n)$ be a sequence of subsets of $X$. The $\limsup E_n$ is defined as follows:  $$\limsup E_n = \bigcap^{\infty}_{m=1} \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=m} E_n .$$

Suppose $(E_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(E_n)$. Will $\limsup E_{n_k}$ differ from $\limsup E_n$ by a zero set or something larger?

I believe their difference is probably a zero set, but how to actually check this?

EDIT: the claim is wrong in general, but would it be correct if we add Cauchy condition ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

$$E_n=\begin{cases}
\Bbb R,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\varnothing,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then $\limsup_nE_n=\Bbb R$, but $\limsup_nE_{2n+1}=\varnothing$.

Comment: What if we require the sequence to be Cauchy? (my previous metric is a complete metric, so it might not work as a good example)

Comment: @haha: I suspect so, though I don’t instantly see an argument. I’d ask that as a separate question in order to get more eyes on it. (By the way, that’s not a metric: it’s only a pseudometric.)

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question to concentrate on some more discrete conditions...

Answer (score 3):

One example might get you started on constructing some of your own: Consider $E_n=\{0\}$ if $n$ is even, and $E_n=\{1\}$ if $n$ is odd. Then $\limsup_n E_n=\{0,1\}$, but $\limsup_k E_{2k}=\{0\}$.

Comment: But a finite set has measure 0

Comment: That depends on the measure you are using.  Also, see Brian M. Scott's answer.